# Objective-C - Accessing class methods inside Initializer method

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a class called SqliteImageAccess that is going to have various methods that provide support for some sqlite functionality. I have a local class variable of type sqlite3 and a class method called opendb. This class method should do one thing and one thing only. Open the database.

The only sticky point here is that my sqlite3 object is going to be an instance variable and Objective-C, for whatever weird reason, doesn't let you access instance variables inside of class methods. Obviously, in other languages, when you instantiate a class, the constructor of that class might call a private method to initialize some local class variables(local private variable perhaps). I want to do the same thing with my sqlite3 object through the equivalent of an Objective-C class constructor method. Perhaps someone can help because I am stuck on this one.

Obviously in another class I can instantiate the SqliteImageAccess class and then call the opendb method. That works fine. I don't want to have to do that. When i instantiate the class the goal is so that the class will handle the opening of the database automatically.

Lastly, with the other methods that are going to be available to do other sqlite work(inserts, etc), i am going to need full access to the db object. thanks in advance for any help.

//SqliteImageAccess.h

```
@interface SqliteImageAccess : NSObject {



}

+(void)opendb; //class method

@end
```

//SqliteImageAccess.m

```
#import "SqliteImageAccess.h"


@implementation SqliteImageAccess

static sqlite3 *db;

+(void)initialize{
    [self opendb];
}

+(void)opendb{
int open = sqlite3_open("/Users/csmith/RPG/cws.sqlite3", &db);
if(open == SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Database was opened successfully");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"open result = %d", open);
}

}

@end
```

Comment: @correction - i moved db over to the implementation file and defined it as static. Also i think that my initialize should actually be -(void)init but i get a warning telling me of conflicting types. Not sure what that is about.

Comment: `init` has to be declared as returning `id` -- a generic pointer. Have you already solved this? It looks like you changed some stuff after you got answers and I can't quite tell what your problem is anymore.

Comment: The warning is because it should be -(id)init instead of -(void)init. The return type is "id".

Comment: i should have been using initialize, not init. that was the issue. the code above has been updated to the current working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interface you declare opendb as a class methode (+) but your are using - in the implementation. Normaly you should get a warning, that your class implementation isn't complete. Change the - to + to implement opendb as a class method and call it via

```
[self opendb];
```

Further, + (void)initilaize is only called once during program life cycle, in think you would like to go with

```
-(id) init;
```

Seeing one more thing, your sqlite3 property is declared as an instance variable, so you can't call it from a class method! You have to move the sqlite3 *db from the .h to the .m file as

```
static sqlite3 *db;
```

after @implementation.

Comment: in my -(void)init{ [self opendb]; } i get a couple of warnings: "SqliteImageAccess may not respond to -opendb and i am still getting the conflicting types for void init. Not to mention now it crashes. I am guess in my case it has to be a class method. so i am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: moving it over the .m file was the crux of the issue here so thanks for the help everyone who pitched in. i have changed my code up above to update what is now working. thanks all again.

Comment: just to validate - yan answered first though everyone helped. no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

observation :

you have declared `opendb` in **.h** as class method.

But in .m class , you are using it as instance method.

```
+(void)opendb{
int open = sqlite3_open("/Users/csmith/RPG/cws.sqlite3", &db);
if(open == SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Database was opened successfully");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"open result = %d", open);
}

}
```

---

Suggest you to have bind both with your instance (class object), and send message to `opendb` explicitly from outside of your class, whenever you create the instance of your database access class.

---

```
- (void) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

       //initialize all your class member here,

    }
}
```

And your opendb instance method function

```
 - (void)opendb{
    int open = sqlite3_open("/Users/csmith/RPG/cws.sqlite3", &db);
    if(open == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Database was opened successfully");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"open result = %d", open);
    }

    }
```

Now lets create the instance of sqllite3 access class.

```
SqliteImageAccess*  smySqliteImageAccess = [SqliteImageAccess  alloc] init];
[smySqliteImageAccess opendb];
```

Answer (score 1):

If all instances of SqliteImageAccess are going to share the same db instance (sqlite3 *), then you can declare it globally instead of declaring it as an instance variable:

//SqliteImageAccess.m

```
@implementation SqliteImageAccess

// 'db' will be shared by all instances of SqliteImageAccess
static sqlite3 *db;

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [SqliteImageAccess class]) {
        opendb(&db); // assumes opendb is a function, not a method
    }
}
```

If you create all instance methods of SqliteImageAccess in this file, `db` will be visible to them.

EDIT: if you don't want to share one `db` instance among all instances of SqliteImageAccess, then you should change `-opendb` to an instance method, and call it in your class's designated initializer (like `-init`). In this case, of course, `-opendb` will have access to the instance variable `db`.